# Catch Invalid Updates - Regexp_LIKE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to catch update statements without WHERE clauses. If a user updates table1, there must be a where clause.

Pattern 1: Wrong format

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 'Test'
```

Pattern 1: Correct format

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 'Test' WHERE ... col1 = ...
```

whereas ... means anything in between.

Pattern 2: Wrong format

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SELECT columnA FROM table2 WHERE rownum = 1)
```

Pattern 2: Correct format

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SELECT columnA FROM table2 WHERE rownum = 1) WHERE ... col1 = ...
```

Since inner query calls table2, the WHERE clause is not mandatory.

Pattern 3: Wrong format

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE rownum = 1)
```

Pattern 3: Correct format

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE rownum = 1 WHERE ... col1 = ...) WHERE ... col1 = ...
```

Pattern 4: Correct format; no where clause is required

```
UPDATE table2 SET columnA = (SELECT columnB FROM table3 WHERE rownum = 1)
```

I plan to write a procedure to catch the wrong update formats. However, I have to figure out the regexp_like syntax at first.

I tried so many ways but couldn't really catch every pattern. Here is the template query I'm experimenting with:

```
WITH tbl AS
(
  SELECT 'UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 999 WHERE col1 = 111' as col1 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SELECT columnA FROM table2 WHERE rownum = 1) WHERE col1 = 111' FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SELECT column2 FROM table1 WHERE rownum = 1 WHERE col1 = 111) WHERE col1 = 111' FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'UPDATE table2 SET columnA = (SELECT columnB FROM table3 WHERE rownum = 1)' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT col1, 'pattern 1' FROM tbl WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (upper(col1), 'UPDATE.*TABLE1.*SET.*WHERE.*col1.*=.*')
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, 'pattern 2' FROM tbl WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (upper(col1), '') -- ???
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, 'pattern 3' FROM tbl WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (upper(col1), '') -- ???
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, 'pattern 4' FROM tbl WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (upper(col1), '') -- ???
```

Assume I'm just trying to search a string. The query will be passed as a string parameter into a stored procedure.

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it's not clear where you want to catch those queries. do you want to search your source code? or prevent the server from executing them?

Comment: I'll catch them in a stored procedure. Basically, the user has to pass the query as a string parameter.

Comment: and regular expressions can't parse sql queries.

Comment: I have to say that letting users execute arbitrary sql is a big hole in your system.

Comment: Assuming users are trusted. This is a hypothetical situation which is meant to use solve a similar problem in the system.

Comment: update big_table set colA=null where 1=1 (or "where colB=colB" would also work, but be bad)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
^UPDATE\s*table1\s*SET\s*\w+\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*WHERE[^\)]*$|^UPDATE\s*((?!table1).)*$
```

- Matches all update statements on tables other than `table1`
- Matches update statements with "`where` clause only" on `table1`

**Note:** Best if used with `g,i and m` modifiers.

See [DEMO and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fV3eT8/3)

Answer (score 0):

If your system is open-ended where the user can pass in an arbitrary select or update statement, catching a missing where clause is not going to really fix the real problem.  But assuming you have to have this, maybe 1 step better might be running an explain plan on each statement before executing it, and then checking the cost or the path options.  For example:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN
    SET STATEMENT_ID = 'BAD1' FOR
SELECT * from big_table;
```

Output:

```
STATEMENT_ID    OPERATION   OPTIONS OPTIMIZER   COST    CARDINALITY
BAD1    SELECT STATEMENT        ALL_ROWS    344119  40523300
BAD1    TABLE ACCESS    FULL    ANALYZED    344119  40523300
```

And a "Good" statement (using an index) might look like:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN
    SET STATEMENT_ID = 'GOOD1' FOR
SELECT * from big_table where colA=123;
```

Output:

```
STATEMENT_ID    OPERATION   OPTIONS OPTIMIZER   COST    CARDINALITY
GOOD1   SELECT STATEMENT        ALL_ROWS    3   1
GOOD1   TABLE ACCESS    BY INDEX ROWID  ANALYZED    3   1
GOOD1   INDEX   UNIQUE SCAN ANALYZED    2   1
```

Note the difference in table access full with high cost vs index scan with low cost.

Anyway, not perfect either, but probably a step better than some regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't do it this way. Even if you trust your users, there is no way you can distinguish a "good" query from a "bad" query (especially with regular expressions).
And letting users directly manipulate the database may break the buisness rules of your system (by mistake or voluntarily)

If you can limit the use cases, maybe a safer alternative would be to let users choose a parameterized update query from a list, and enter the parameters. I am asuming you can't or don't want to give them an appropriate user interface.